# How to get amplitude of media player in Android ?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to develop an vu-meter and it reacts with sound, like a [live-wallpaper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv1d95_y8HA)
Can anybody help me...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude

This method returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call to this method. Call this only after the setAudioSource().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: OP asked for MediaPlayer, not MediaRecorder.